# Multiple Host Headers and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Following some great posts here led me to the following link.
http://www.apterasoftware.com/Blog/Post/10-01-09/Hosting_WCF_Web_Services_on_a_site_with_multiple_host_header_bindings.aspx

I am using .Net 3.5 but am trying to use the ServiceFactory found at the link.  The problem I'm having is that I'm receiving the error:
"The CLR Type 'WCFReportLibrary.MultipleHeaderServiceHostFactory' could not be loaded during service compilation."

I have created a solution with two projects.  A WCFReportLibrary which contains the [ServiceContract] and the MultipleHeaderServiceHostFactory class.  In my web project within the solution I have created the .svc file with the <%@ ServiceHost Factory @> directive set to "WCFReportLibrary.MultipleHeaderServiceHostFactory".  Am I not able to load the factory in this way?  Thanks again!